# Remove temp workspaces

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm using team build in TFS2010 with the default template with some minor changes in it regarding versioning process.

Each time I run a build for one of my build definitions it creates a temp workspace in my TFSBuild server under the user which runs the build.

Almost every time I run the build again i'm getting this error:
**The path XXXXXX is already mapped in workspace 100_2_TFS2010-Build01.**
But, sometimes it works (unstable).

How can I remove those temp workspaces before the build run?
I see in the default template that it's suppose to clean workspace but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've seen this too, but it was never consistent enough that I could identify the root cause. I haven't seen it in a long time, but we're at 2013 update 4 now so maybe they fixed it.

Comment: Unfortunately to me it happens almost everytime. I was advised to use tf workfold /unmap but it doesn't seem to work, each time I get a different syntax error which seems weird because I put the parameters exactly as was asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently using two build agents under one controller (configuration I used now) caused this problem.

Disabling one of them solve my issue and now everything works fine.